# Create NW.js with using webview but no shadowprotect

Tags: javascript, webview, shadow-dom, nw.js

Hej sry when I ask but is there a way to use the webview tag in an nw.js application without that everything under the webview is covered in an shadow-root?

```
<webview id="foo" src="file:///C:/Users/midjo/Desktop/TEST.html" style="display:flex; height:100%; width:100%;" partition="trusted" tabindex="-1">
```

## shadow-root(open)

Answer (score 0):

No, but shadow-root is Ok, it's easy to do whatever you want with DOM inside.
For example:

```
<webview id="foo" src="test.html" partition="trusted" style="display: flex;"></webview>
<script>
    foo.addEventListener('loadstop', e => {
        foo.executeScript({
            code: `document.querySelector('body').innerText;`
        }, result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can get any content, click things and even inject any js-file.